# Efficiently Find Every Number with the Digit Six xor Eight in it for a Given Range

Tags: c++

I have to take two numbers and find all numbers (inclusive) between those two numbers with the digits 6 or 8 in them, but not both. So an input of `6 8` would return `2`, while an input of `60 69` would return `9` (as 68 isn't counted).

This is a very simple thing to do, but I have to do this in less than a second, even with numbers in the quadrillions. The fact that this is impossible to do iteratively makes me wonder if there's some basic trick to skip checking 99% of the numbers that I'm missing. The most I've been able to optimize this is by being able to make jumps of 10^`[two less than the number of digits in the difference between the two numbers]`, let's define that exponent as `d`. I made my program make these jumps when the number had the digits 6 and 8, or neither of those digits, and ended in at least `d` zeros. If the number had neither the digits 6 and 8, the value of the number of numbers with 6 or 8 between 1 and 10^`d` is added to the number of special numbers (this first value that is added having been saved in an array in memory).

In any case, the best way I think I can demonstrate my attempted solution is by presenting my code. Though, if you have an suggestions for improving my question, feel free to make them.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int_fast64_t low; //starting number
    int_fast64_t high; //ending number
    std::cin >> low >> high; std::cin.ignore();
    /*Starts out holding the difference between high and low,
    then will hold two less than the number of digits in that difference*/
    int_fast64_t lowHighDifference = high - low;
    //10 to various powers used to not have to iterate over every number between low & high
    static int_fast64_t pow10[] = {0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};
    //The number of numbers with 6 xor 8 between 1 and 10^index
    static int_fast64_t numspecial[] = {0, 2, 34, 434, 4930, 52562, 538594, 5371634, 52539010, 506405522};
    //Find how large the jumps one can make are based on the difference between high and low
    for (int_fast8_t iterator = 9; iterator > 0; iterator--) {
        if (lowHighDifference > pow10[iterator]) {
            /*This needs to have two fewer digits than the difference between low & high,
                otherwise it risks not being used*/
            lowHighDifference = iterator - 1;
            iterator = 0;
        }
    }
    /*Incremented by one every time a number with 6 xor 8 is ecountered,
    and by numspecial[lowHighDifference] every time a number without 6 or 8,
    and at least as many zeros at the end as pow10[lowHighDifference] is encountered*/
    int_fast64_t specialNumbers = 0;
    for (int_fast64_t iterator = low; iterator <= high; iterator++) {
        char stringNum[21]; //long ints can't have more than 20 digits
        /*Copy iterator into a string to check each digit individually,
            while recording the length that string ends up being. */
        int_fast8_t stringNumLength = sprintf(stringNum, "%ld", iterator),
            /*Starts at 0, will turn to 6 or 8 with the first of those found,
                then will be set to -1 if the other number is found */
            sixOrEight = 0;
        for (int_fast8_t stringNumIterator = 0; stringNumIterator < stringNumLength; stringNumIterator++) {
            if (stringNum[stringNumIterator] == '8') {
                if (sixOrEight == 6) {
                    sixOrEight = -1;
                    stringNumIterator = stringNumLength;
                }
                else
                    sixOrEight = 8;
            }
            else if (stringNum[stringNumIterator] == '6') {
                if (sixOrEight == 8) {
                    sixOrEight = -1;
                    stringNumIterator = stringNumLength;
                }
                else
                    sixOrEight = 6;
            }
        }
        /*The basic case in which a six or an eight was found. I don't know how I can optimize this,
        but it's the main part slowing this program down. */
        if (sixOrEight > 0) {
            specialNumbers++;
        }
        else if (lowHighDifference > 0) {
            //If neither six or eight were found
            if (sixOrEight == 0) {
                if (iterator % pow10[lowHighDifference] == 0 && pow10[lowHighDifference] < (high - iterator)) {
                    specialNumbers += numspecial[lowHighDifference];
                    iterator += pow10[lowHighDifference] - 1;
                }
            } //If sixOrEight is < 0 and iterator has at least as many zeros at the end as pow10[lowHighDifference]
            else if (iterator % pow10[lowHighDifference] == 0) {
                //Add 10^lowHighDifference to iterator without adding to specialNumbers
                iterator += pow10[lowHighDifference] - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << specialNumbers;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your suspicions are right: this is a mathematical trick. This question must be coming from one of those senseless online quiz/hacking/coding sites, and the answer to these kind of puzzles always involves a mathematical trick, and little to do with C++. If someone's goal -- and if your goal too -- is to actually learn C++, I'm afraid that nothing here will actually turn out to be of any use towards the goal of knowing and mastering C++. This is a meaningless mathematical trick, and nothing more than that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am curious to know that mathematical trick. My knowledge of C++ is pretty proficient.

Comment: Well, let's say you wanted to know how many three digit numbers exist where the first digit is either 6 or 8, but none of the other two digits are what the first digit is. Would you then try all numbers from 100 to 999, brute force style, and count which ones fit that criteria? Of course not. This particular calculation is laughably easy to make, using simple math. In the given problem, the calculation is obviously different, and there are a few complicating factors that add a few complexities, but it's basically the same thing. I'm sure you can figure it out, if you think about it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The solution that comes to mind is what I tried to do by saving the number of numbers with 6 xor 8 between 1 and 10, 1 and 100 etcetera, and that barely sped it up. I also looked at this forum post and it makes absolutely ZERO sense to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474985/algorithm-to-find-number-of-integers-with-given-digits-within-a-given-range

Comment: I have a full solution. Posting shortly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full solution at bottom of this post**

It took a few hours to cook this up, but I think I have the optimal solution.  Thanks for providing this challenge. Number computational problems are a hobby of mine (to a fault).

**TERMINOLOGY**

First some terminology I invented just for this problem:

**NQ** or "Non-qualified".  An NQ number is one that has neither a `6` nor `8` in its set of digits.

**Q6** or "Qualified by 6" is any number with a `6` in its sets of digits, but no eights.

**Q8** or "Qualified by 8" is any number with a `8` in its sets of digits, but no sixes.

**PNQ** or "Permanently non-qualified".  This is a number with both a 6 or 8 in it.

Any NQ number can become qualified simply by appending a `6` or `8` to the end of it. (e.g. `123` is NQ, but `1236` is "qualified")

The reason why I used this "qualified" term is because the solution needs to be thought in terms of building a numbers as a string of digits from left to right.  For example, a non-qualified number such as `123` can become qualified simply by appending a `6` onto it. By appending a `6` onto `123`, the number becomes `1236` and is Q6.

Any qualified number can become permanently non-qualified by appending a `6` or `8` to it such that it has both digits.  For example, `654` is Q6, but if we append an `8` onto it, it comes permanently non-qualified.  Any additional digits prepended onto this number will still result in the number being PNQ.

**Slow solution**

So let's introduce the first batch of code. A formalized enum of what I just discussed above:

```
enum class NumberType : int
{
    NQ,    // NQ is "non-qualifying". It's a number with neither a six or an eight
    Q6,    // Q6 is "qualified by 6".  It's a number with at least a single six digit, but no eights
    Q8,    // Q8 is "qualified by 8".  It's a number with at least a single eight digit, but no sixes
    PNQ    // PNQ is "permanently non qualified". It's a number with both a six and an eight in it
};
```

And let's introduce a helper function that can take any 64-bit number and tell us what type it is:

```
NumberType GetNumberType(uint64_t value)
{
    uint64_t sixCount = 0;
    uint64_t eightCount = 0;
    NumberType result = NumberType::NQ;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        uint64_t lastDigit = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        if (lastDigit == 6)
        {
            sixCount++;
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 8)
        {
            eightCount++;
        }
    }
    if (sixCount && eightCount)
    {
        result = NumberType::PNQ;
    }
    else if (sixCount)
    {
        result =  NumberType::Q6;
    }
    else if (eightCount)
    {
        result = NumberType::Q8;
    }
    else
    {
        result = NumberType::NQ;
    }
    return result;
}
```

At this point we could easily build a brute force solution to compute the count of Q6 or Q8 numbers within a given range.

```
uint64_t GetSixXorEightCount_BruteForceSlow(uint64_t start, uint64_t end)
{
     uint64_t count = 0;
     for (auto x = start; x <= end; x++)
     {
         NumberType nt = GetNumberType(x);
         count += ((nt == NumberType::Q6) || (nt == NumberType::Q8)) ? 1 : 0;
     }
     return count;
}
```

But once we start to get into a range with billions numbers that won't scale.

**Number patterns**

Now something about digits I noticed.

Take all the single digit numbers excluding zero:

- 7 NQ numbers (1,2,3,4,5,7,9)
- 1 Q6 number  (6)
- 1 Q8 number  (8)
- 0 in PNQ

Take all the two digit numbers between 10 and 99.  If you do a cursory scan of those numbers, you'll find that the following stats hold true:

- 56 NQ numbers (e.g. 23, 45, 79, etc..)
- 16 Q6 numbers (60-67, 69, 16,26,36,46,56,76,96)
- 16 Q8 numbers (80-85, 87-89, 18,28,38,48,58,78,96)
- 2 PNQ numbers (68 and 86)

And to compute the stats for all 3 digit numbers, you don't have to do a brute force search. You'll realize the following:

- All the NQ numbers in the 2 digit range can be appended with one of 8 digits to compute the NQ set.  Hence the total number of NQ for 3 digits is simply 56*8.
- All the Q6 and Q8 numbers can remain qualified by appending one of 9 digits onto it.  Further, any NQ number from the 2-digit range can be added to the Q6 or Q8 set simply by adding a 6 or 8.

And so it follows, a general formlua for figuring out how many types of numbers are in any set of N digit numbers:

- countof_nq(N)  == countof_nq(N-1)*8
- countof_q6(N)  == countof_q6(N-1)*9 + countof_nq(N-1)
- countof_q8(N)  == countof_q8(N-1)*9 + countof_nq(N-1)
- countof_pnq(N) == countof_pnq(N-1) * 10 + countof_q6(N-1) + countof_q8(N-1)

Now if the problem space was "compute the count of N digit numbers with 6 xor 8", then the recursion function would be easy.  But how do you compute ranges of numbers within different digit boundaries?

**Example break down**

Let's say you want to find the range of qualifying numbers between `125` and `455`.

You start by recursively breaking the problem down from `125-455` by chopping off digits.

Solve for `12-45` first, which requires solving for `1-4` before then. Then apply the formula for counting up into the next digit range.  But you have to add a repair step to uncount the numbers not in range (120-124 and 456-459).

```
SolveFor(125-455):
    SolveFor(12-45)
       SolveFor(1-4) => {Q6:0, Q8:0, NQ: 4}
    Compute for 10-49 => {Q6: 4, Q8: 4, NQ: 32}
    Repair for 12-45 by uncounting 10,11,46,47,48,and 49 from the stats set => {{Q6: 3, Q8: 3, NQ: 28}
Compute for 120-459 => {Q6:55, Q8:55, NQ: 224}
Repair for 125-455 by uncounting 120-124 and uncounting for 456-459 => {Q6:54, Q8:54, NQ: 217}
```

**Final Solution**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class NumberType : int
{
    NQ,    // NQ is "non-qualifying". It's a number with neither a six or an eight
    Q6,    // Q6 is "qualified by 6".  It's a number with at least a single six digit, but no eights
    Q8,    // Q8 is "qualified by 8".  It's a number with at least a single eight digit, but no sixes
    PNQ    // PNQ is "permanently non qualified". It's a number with both a six and an eight in it
};

struct range_stats
{
    uint64_t nq;            // number of "non-qualifying numbers" that have neither 6 nor 8 in any digit
    uint64_t pnq;           // number of "permanently non-qualifying" numbers tht have both a 6 or 8
    uint64_t q6;            // number of qualifying numbers that have at least one occurance of 6, but not 8
    uint64_t q8;            // number of qualifying numbers that have at least one occurance of 8, but not 6
};

NumberType GetNumberType(uint64_t value)
{
    uint64_t sixCount = 0;
    uint64_t eightCount = 0;
    NumberType result;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        uint64_t lastDigit = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        if (lastDigit == 6)
        {
            sixCount++;
        }
        else if (lastDigit == 8)
        {
            eightCount++;
        }
    }
    if (sixCount && eightCount)
    {
        result = NumberType::PNQ;
    }
    else if (sixCount)
    {
        result =  NumberType::Q6;
    }
    else if (eightCount)
    {
        result = NumberType::Q8;
    }
    else
    {
        result = NumberType::NQ;
    }
    return result;
}

void DeductStats(range_stats& stats, NumberType nt)
{
    switch (nt)
    {
        case NumberType::Q6:
        {
            stats.q6--; 
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::Q8:
        {
            stats.q8--;
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::NQ:
        {
            stats.nq--;
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::PNQ:
        {
            stats.pnq--;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void AddStats(range_stats& stats, NumberType nt)
{
    switch (nt)
    {
        case NumberType::Q6:
        {
            stats.q6++;
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::Q8:
        {
            stats.q8++;
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::NQ:
        {
            stats.nq++;
            break;
        }
        case NumberType::PNQ:
        {
            stats.pnq++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void GetStatsForRange(uint64_t start, uint64_t end, range_stats& stats)
{
    // ASSUMES START AND END HAVE THE SAME NUMBER OF DIGITS

    if (end < 10)
    {
        uint64_t sum = 0;
        stats = {};
        for (auto i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if (i == 6)
            {
                stats.q6++;
            }
            else if (i == 8)
            {
                stats.q8++;
            }
            else if (i > 0)
            {
                stats.nq++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        uint64_t newStart = start / 10;
        uint64_t newEnd = end / 10;
        uint64_t repairStart = (start / 10) * 10;   // convert 123 to 120
        uint64_t repairEnd = (end / 10) * 10 + 9;   // convert 567 to 569
        range_stats lowerStats = {};
        GetStatsForRange(newStart, newEnd, lowerStats);

        stats.nq = lowerStats.nq * 8;
        stats.q6 = lowerStats.q6 * 9 + lowerStats.nq;
        stats.q8 = lowerStats.q8 * 9 + lowerStats.nq;
        stats.pnq = lowerStats.pnq * 10 + lowerStats.q6 + lowerStats.q8;

        // now repair the stats by accounting for the ones that aren't in range
        for (uint64_t i = repairStart; i < start; i++)
        {
            auto nt = GetNumberType(i);
            DeductStats(stats, nt);
        }
        for (uint64_t i = repairEnd; i > end; i--)
        {
            auto nt = GetNumberType(i);
            DeductStats(stats, nt);
        }
    }
}


bool InRange(uint64_t value, uint64_t minimum, uint64_t maximum)
{
    return ((value >= minimum) && (value <= maximum));
}

bool IntersectionOfRanges(uint64_t levelStart, uint64_t levelEnd, uint64_t start, uint64_t end, uint64_t& newStart, uint64_t& newEnd)
{
    // ASSERT START <= END

    bool startInRange = InRange(start, levelStart, levelEnd);
    bool endInRange = InRange(end, levelStart, levelEnd);

    if ((end < levelStart) || (start > levelEnd))
    {
        return false; // no intersection
    }

    if (!startInRange && endInRange)
    {
        newStart = levelStart;
        newEnd = end;
    }

    else if (startInRange && endInRange)
    {
        newStart = start;
        newEnd = end;
    }
    else if (startInRange)
    {

        newStart = start;
        newEnd = levelEnd;
    }
    else
    {
        newStart = levelStart;
        newEnd = levelEnd;
    }
    return true;
}


void bruteForceTest(uint64_t start, uint64_t end, range_stats& stats)
{
    stats = {};
    for (auto i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        auto nt = GetNumberType(i);
        AddStats(stats, nt);
    }
}

uint64_t GetSixXorEightCount(uint64_t start, uint64_t end)
{

    range_stats stats = {};
    range_stats expected = {};
    range_stats results = {};

    if (start == 0)
    {
        start = 1;
    }

    if (start > end)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    uint64_t levelStart = 1;
    uint64_t levelEnd = 9;

    while (levelStart <= end)
    {
        uint64_t normalizedStart;
        uint64_t normalizedEnd;
        if (IntersectionOfRanges(levelStart, levelEnd, start, end, normalizedStart, normalizedEnd))
        {
            stats = {};
            GetStatsForRange(normalizedStart, normalizedEnd, stats);
            results.nq += stats.nq;
            results.q6 += stats.q6;
            results.q8 += stats.q8;
            results.pnq += stats.pnq;
        }

        levelStart = levelStart * 10;
        levelEnd = levelEnd * 10 + 9;
    }


    cout << "For the range of numbers between " << start << " and " << end << endl;
    cout << "Q6:  " << results.q6 << endl;
    cout << "Q8:  " << results.q8 << endl;
    cout << "NQ:  " << results.nq << endl;
    cout << "PNQ: " << results.pnq << endl;

    //cout << "Brute force computing expected" << endl;
    //bruteForceTest(start, end, expected);
    //cout << "Expected Q6:  " << expected.q6 << endl;
    //cout << "Expected Q8:  " << expected.q8 << endl;
    //cout << "Expected NQ:  " << expected.nq << endl;
    //cout << "Expected PNQ: " << expected.pnq << endl;

    return results.q6 + results.q8;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t start = 0;
    uint64_t end = 0;

    cout << "Starting number:\n";
    cin >> start;
    cout << "Ending number:\n";
    cin >> end;

    uint64_t result = GetSixXorEightCount(start, end);

    std::cout << "There are " << result << " qualifying numbers in range that have a six or eight, but not both\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn dude. I haven't had the time to read through all of that, but the amount of effort you put into making this explantion for my small brain is greatly appreciated. I'll probably need a clarifying detail or two as to why your answer works efficiently, but this obviously works, so I'll mark it as the accepted answer right now.

Comment: Feel free to ask.  Is this for learning, homework, leetcode, or something else?

Comment: My own curiosity. I already submitted the answer to this that didn't complete this in less than a second, so I can't really improve on that interview question, but in the hour I was given to produce a solution for that question, this really burrowed itself into my brain, making me desperate to understand the math trick behind it. I will say that I'm having a hell of a time trying to understand your psuedocode before your final solution. Though, that might be because I'm not understanding the explanation before that. Why do you have to go 2 lower then start and 1 higher than end?

Comment: This was for a job interview? That's a vicious problem to expect anyone to complete within an hour - and doesn't prove much about your capabilities as an engineer.  What do you mean by "2 lower than start and 1 higher than end?"  Which line/function in the code are you asking about?

Comment: I'm referencing this:

"Let's say you want to find the range of qualifying numbers between 125 and 455.

You start by recursively breaking the problem down from 123-456 by chopping off digits."

Comment: That was a typo.  It should have consistently said `125-455`.